# Speaker diarization for 3+ speakers using Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

Does Azure's batch transcription support speaker diarization for more than 2 speakers?

I checked their [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/batch-transcription) documentation and didn't find anything relevant.

Are there other ways to do this using Azure cognitive services?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use one of the Azure Cognitive services which is Conversation transcription.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/conversation-transcription